# stopping rosbag record from script

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a python subprocess that starts recording a topic through rosbag:

```
    self.ros_bag_recorder = subprocess.Popen(['rosbag', 'record', '-O',
                                             os.path.expanduser('~/some_address),
                                             '/the_topic'],
                                            env=self.venv,
                                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  
                                            stderr=sys.stderr
                                             )
```

which normally I would have executed in a terminal and after pressing ctrl+c the recording was stopped ( the bag file from .bag.active would have changed to .bag).
However now that I have started it through suprocess and want to also stop it with an script rather than terminal, commands such as followings haven't worked:

```
    self.ros_bag_recorder.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
```

or

```
    self.ros_bag_recorder.send_signal(signal.SIGKILL)
```

or

```
    self.ros_bag_recorder.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

Does anyone know a way to stop the recording similar to when we just press ctrl+c in terminal?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367930/stopping-rosbag-record-from-script/) by [azerila](https://answers.ros.org/users/52921/azerila/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As answered to another similar question (https://answers.ros.org/question/286871/how-record-rosbag-with-python/), you can kill it by running this:

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if "record" in proc.name() and set(command[2:]).issubset(proc.cmdline()):
        proc.send_signal(subprocess.signal.SIGINT)

self.ros_bag_recorder.send_signal(subprocess.signal.SIGINT)
```

---

Originally posted by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) with karma: 641 on 2020-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [azerila](https://answers.ros.org/users/52921/azerila/) on 2020-12-17**:
is 'command' the same as the command that was used as input to Popen?

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2020-12-17**:
Yes, exactly.